# Obstacle detection using turtlebot w/kinect

Tags: turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new to ROS and not very familiar with it. I am currently following tutorials and currently able to make the turtlebot2 move forward with a script but now I want to detect an obstacle with the kinect and stop. Not too sure how I would go about doing this, any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315294/obstacle-detection-using-turtlebot-w/kinect/) by [GroggyROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/39965/groggyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start with the moveit [tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html).
Then get a bit familiar with moveit, especially follow the Moveit Setup Assistant, Moveit Perception Pipeline Tutorial.

Find a good and simple .urdf for the kinect and then set it up according to this [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjgEdRJ72Tw). Then you can follow the [planning scene tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/planning_scene/planning_scene_tutorial.html) to setup a collision checking node.

It will be a bit hard at first, but keep trying. You will get it.
There probably is another way to do this, I am not totally sure, but watch [this too](https://youtu.be/q3Dn5U3cSWk), it might help you.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Apurva](https://answers.ros.org/users/38530/apurva/) with karma: 36 on 2019-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GroggyROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/39965/groggyros/) on 2019-02-27**:
Thanks for answering!